# How to run java process to be seen not as 'java...' in processes list?

Tags: bash, process, java, process-management, ps

Is it possible to run a Java process in Linux in a way that it could be seen in `ps` as some sort of alias? It would be easier to restart it when it is down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool(`[**jps**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/jps/)`)`:

```
[Tue Aug 30@17:02:14][prince@localhost ~]$ jps -l
30207 sun.tools.jps.Jps
29947 org.netbeans.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the options to `ps` that let you see the parameters (i.e. main class name)
2. Create a softlink to `java.exe`, with the name you desire, and use that to run the program. (untested)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a description of how to change the program name](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/processname.html).
It is done by changing the first program argument `argv[0]`, which contains the program name. This makes it necessary to write a small wrapper around the Java binary.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting a program when it is down could be done very differently. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
jstart () {
    java -cp /foo/bar baz.Main 
    jstart 
}
```

Start your script, and if the program terminates, it gets restarted immediately.

You have to hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd>  to terminate your script, or kill the script by name.